# Is it better to use an image component or to draw on a canvas?

Tags: sprites, image

I am developping a small 2D RPG with JavaFX, although my question might apply to any toolkit or even any language for the matter.

I have two choices to display the characters, the scenery, the items and other displays such as a life bar or an inventory:

1. Put them in `imageView` printed on top of a background.
2. Draw them directly on the canvas (`graphicsContext`) of the background.

Which is the best practice? Is there a significant difference in term of speed, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever option is easier for you to work with, you are unlikely to push the hardware limits with a 2d game so you should get a good framerate with either approach.

Using a Group and place components in it means you can detect mouse clicks on each element the same as any other JavaFX control.

Drawing into a Canvas is more similar to how a fully fledged OpenGL/DirectX game would work, and it's also much more like how HTML5/Javascript would work if you ever want to make a web version of your game. But you lose all built in JavaFX control support and have to calculate what element the user clicks on or performs drag drop with yourself.

If you wish to make more advanced graphics later on I would go for the latter option, but only if your not sure which option to pick, otherwise go with whatever your leaning towards already.